# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor view returning multiple values for a Html.CheckBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, razor

I have a View that contains the following Line of code:

```
//(DaysOfWeek is a bool[])
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Data.DaysOfWeek[0])
```

It starts off as false.  When the user "checks" the box and returns, it returns a value for both true and false;

Here is what is being passed back as part of the form data

```
Data.DaysOfWeek[0]:true
Data.DaysOfWeek[0]:false
```

Why is it doing that?

Comment: Although @RoryMcCrossan explained the why, and a answer, I have never seen this problem, doing what you are doing. Could you post your view model, I would think `bool DayOfWeek0 = Data.DaysOfWeek[0]` should be either `true` or `false` if you're not using a view model, you could just do `@Html.CheckBox("VariableName")` and in your controller method arguments `bool VariableName`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because standard HTML checkboxes return no value if unchecked. To make this annoying behaviour more intuitive, the `CheckBoxFor` method creates a checkbox and a hidden control with the same name, with a value of `false`, something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myControl" value="True" /> My control
<input type="hidden" name="myControl" value="False" />
```

What you will see when the form is posted is either:

```
False // checkbox unchecked
True,False // checkbox was checked
```

Therefore, to test if the box was checked you should use `Contains('True')`:

```c#
bool checkboxChecked = formCollection["myControl"].Contains("True");
```

Comment: This pestilent feature is also resolved when using binding libraries, such as knockout.js...binding directly to a Boolean occurs flawlessly. I find it best to not use RazorFor syntax in most situations, but if you still do, the checked property can be overridden with a data-bind attribute and works great.